# how to solve error 1778 on mysql server 5.7.12 multi source replication on windows 64

Tags: mysql, replication

```
Cannot execute statements with implicit commit inside a transaction when 
 @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT == 'UUID:NUMBER'. Error_code: 1778
```

this is the error message in the error log file
 slave sql running is stopped

this is the end of slave relay log file

```
  SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= '936028d7-04b9-11e6-ac6d-d4ae52cbf622:4433'/*!*/;
  # at 13112
  #160420  9:28:21 server id 1000  end_log_pos 8568551 CRC32 0x2b059bc7         
  Query thread_id=55    exec_time=4294966951    error_code=0
  SET TIMESTAMP=1461133701/*!*/;
  BEGIN
  /*!*/;
  # at 13175
  #160420  7:11:11 server id 600  end_log_pos 13242 CRC32 0xcc67c190       
  Rotate to p6-relay-bin-p1.000043  pos: 4
  ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
  SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
   DELIMITER ;
   # End of log file
   /*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
   /*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```